# Any advanced iOS user know what are the following iOS processes?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, process

Any advanced iOS user know what are the following iOS processes?

1. `/usr/libexec/spd`
2. `/usr/libexec/lsd`
3. `/sbin/punchd`

Comment: 2. `/usr/libexec/lsd` : [See answer here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155431/what-is-process-lsd-on-ios)

Answer (score 2):

on a jailbroken ios device snowbreeze used to rename launchd to punchd I am not sure if this is still the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dpkg with the S parameter (capital 'S') to determine which package contained a specific file.  For example:

dpkg -S lsd

on my iphone it returns:
bigbosshackertools: /usr/bin/installsdk3

Comment: All that does is find packages with files with "lsd" in name somewehere. Since that command returns "/usr/bin/installsdk3" (which contains the string "lsd") and not "/usr/libexec/lsd", the latter file isn't part of any jailbroken package.